# HOw to remove white thin border inside regular border from WPF button

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Everytime, I add WPF button, I get white thin border inside border, how should I remove that?

Here is XAMl for button

```
  <Button BorderThickness="1" Content="Calculate" Height="25" 
        Foreground="Black" Background="#FF35C57D" 
        BorderBrush="#FF28B363" OpacityMask="#FF35C57D" />
```

[image]

**update**
I am adding blend template copy for reference, its thin border inside regular border.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"   
                    Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static  
                        SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"  
                          StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Are you on Windows 7?

Comment: Yes, it has to do with OS?

Comment: I put your button in a new Wpf project and I am running windows 8 and there is no white.

Comment: What if you add `Padding="0"`?

Comment: @carpenter Padding="0" didn't help!

Comment: do you have some default button style some where in your resources ?

Comment: @eranotzap Nope! there is no common styles in resource, FYI I also have VS Blend 2012, IF I add button in blend it shows white inner border there,

Comment: drop it in blend. make a copy of the original style and post it in your question. please. this might have something to do with the ButtonChrome

Comment: @eranotzap added blend copy, thanks

Comment: try replacing ButtonChrome with a simple Border. don't forget to remove all the dp's from it that do not exist of Border. If i remmember correctly the Chrome element "has mind of it's own".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange your `Button Template` like the following code (a `Border` as Parent Of the `ContentPresenter` and remove `Themes:ButtonChrome` from your codes.)

```
<Style x:Key="NoChromeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    ..... OTHER CODES ....
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="7" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    ..... OTHER CODES ....
</Style>
```

Comment: What about rounded corners?

Comment: So I'm happy Jack ;)... If this answer is useful for you please `MARK` it as correct answer.